# How should I implement this stopwatch/time counter using Date() in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm building an app using Phonegap that involves pressing a button that starts a counter for seconds/minutes/hours until you press stop, and displays it. I had it working when the device's screen was on using a setInterval and a series of if statements like:

```
setInterval(function () {
    if (buttonpress === true) {
        second += 1;
        if (second > 59) {
            minute += 1;
            second = 0;
        };
        //etc to minute and hour
    };
};
```

Problem was, I needed to implement a background service in order to keep the setInterval/stopwatch counting up when the device's screen was off, which was going to be a pretty big hassle. It just occurred to me that I could simply get a current time using "var local = new Date();" and "local.getMinutes/Hours/Seconds();"

I can understand that this probably wasn't the best way to implement a counter like this in the first place, which is why I'm having a bit of trouble implementing the new counter based on the time of day.
I'm having trouble with getting the initial time when the button is pressed, translating that into how much time has passed since it was pressed, and displaying that in the setInterval to where if you turn your device's screen off, it'll display the accurate lapsed time when you turn the screen back on. 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Look into moment.js perhaps. It is my go to for anything date/time related in javascript.

http://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you're trying to measure.   Are you just trying to measure how long the button is pressed for?  If so, then you don't need an interval timer at all.   Just record the time at button down and then check the time at button up and subtract the two to see how long it was down.

Comment: Yes I just have a toggle button and I want it to display in real time how long it has been since you initially pressed the button, until you stop it. That's why I need a setInterval, for it to look for changes and display them.

Comment: It wouldn't be difficult except when I take the start time minus the current time, and for example it started at 8:59 and was stopped at 9:02, giving me a result of -57, you know? Same with the seconds, and the hours if you start it late at night at 23:04, then stop it at 01:04 and get -22 instead of the correct result of 2.